# Checking to see if a selected list of items are in another table

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to come up with some code to check whether or not a user owns a list of items. The list of items can be any length but will probably be no more than 5.

There are 2 tables involved here: qrequirements and inventory.

I've got as far as running a loop to check a user has each item, but I'm stuck on how to record the result of the ownership of each item and how this can be communicated to the user afterwards.

I might be going about all this the wrong way and maybe there's a simpler way, I don't know.

Any help would be great. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php

// Get the list of required items
$result = mysql_query("select * from qrequirements where qid='2'");
// This might return E.G:
// item1 = '32'
// item2 = '24'
// item3 = '15'

// Loop through each item to check the user has it
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $itemid = $row["itemid"];
    $check_inv = mysql_query("select * from inventory where userid='$userid' AND item = $itemid");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check_inv);
    if($num_rows>=1){
        // Something in here to confirm the item is owned by the user, while we check the others
    }else{
        echo "You do not have this item";
    }
}

// Notify the user if they have all items required

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the items that a user needs but does not have can be solved by a single query. The below query should accomplish that task.

```
SELECT * FROM qrequirements t1
 WHERE t1.quid = '2'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM inventory t2
                 WHERE t1.item = t2.item
                   AND t2.userid = '$userid')
```

If you also need to know which items the user does have then this similar query will accomplish that additional task.

```
SELECT * FROM qrequirements t1
 WHERE t1.quid = '2'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM inventory t2
                 WHERE t1.item = t2.item
                   AND t2.userid = '$userid')
```

Another useful query is one that would return the required items and an indicator of whether the user has that item. The item_count will be 0 if the user does not have the item and greater than 0 if the user does have the item.

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM inventory t2
               WHERE t1.item = t2.item
                 AND t2.userid = '$userid') as item_count
 FROM qrequirements t1
WHERE t1.quid = '2'
```

Comment: Thanks for that but this doesn't really help with the main issue. I'd still need to add this query to a loop to check each item, and that leaves me with code similar to what I had. The problem is that I still need to provide one final boolean result on whether the user has all items. At the moment I'm checking one at a time but cannot seem to bring them all together for a final boolean result.

Comment: Maybe I need to be more clear on what I'm trying to do but its hard to explain :)

Comment: It might be easier to imagine a web page with a box containing a list of the required items and a submit button. The user can only click on the submit button if they have all the required items in their inventory. This is the general gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I do not see why you would still need a loop. If the first query returns any records then the user does not have all the needed items therefore you set the boolean result to false.

Answer (score 0):

try this as a sql only version:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(DISTINCT r.itemid) = COUNT(DISTINCT i.itemid), 1, 0) as met_reqirements
FROM qrequirements r
    LEFT JOIN inventory i ON i.itemid = r.item_id AND i.userid = '$userid'
WHERE r.qid = 2
```